# how can i create pagination from a single table using group_by and count_all_results Codigniter

Tags: count, group-by, codeigniter-3

I have two tables 
1.

```
order_log

order_id  order_status provider_id more
  1              2            2     ...
  2              2            1     ...
  3              0            1     ...
  4              3            2     ...
  5              1            3     ...
  6              1            1     ...
  7              4            2     ...
...
```

and another table

```
provider table
   provider_id   provider_name
    1               vodafone
    2                   xyz
    3                   abc
    4                   njk
....
```

here is my code to get data from table

```
$this->load->model('ordermodel');
    $order_status=$this->ordermodel->getOrderStatus();


    $this->db->select($this->orderLogTable.'.operator_id,'.$this->orderLogTable.'.order_status,COUNT('.$this->db->dbprefix($this->orderLogTable).'.order_status) AS numofstatus, SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix($this->orderLogTable).'.order_customer_amount) AS totalamount,'.$this->operatorTable.'.operator_name, SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix($this->orderLogTable).'.order_retailer_discount_amount) AS totaldiscountamount');
    $this->db->from($this->operatorTable);
    $this->db->join($this->orderLogTable,$this->orderLogTable.'.operator_id ='.$this->operatorTable.'.operator_id AND '.'date(' . $this->db->dbprefix($this->orderLogTable) . '.order_complete_date) BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromdate)) . '" and"' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todate)) . '" AND '.$this->orderLogTable.'.order_status IN ('.$order_status['cancel'].','.$order_status['success'].','.$order_status['pending'].')','left');
    $this->db->group_by(array($this->orderLogTable.'.order_status',$this->operatorTable.'.operator_id'));
    $this->db->order_by($this->operatorTable.'.operator_id');
    if ($limit !== NULL && $offset !== NULL) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
     }
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

and getting the result perfectly

but when I am trying to get pagination count

```
$this->load->model('ordermodel');
        $order_status=$this->ordermodel->getOrderStatus();
        $this->db->select($this->operatorTable.'.operator_id,'.$this->orderLogTable.'.order_status');
        $this->db->from($this->operatorTable);
        $this->db->join($this->orderLogTable,$this->orderLogTable.'.operator_id ='.$this->operatorTable.'.operator_id AND '.'date(' . $this->db->dbprefix($this->orderLogTable) . '.order_complete_date) BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromdate)) . '" and"' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todate)) . '" AND '.$this->orderLogTable.'.order_status IN ('.$order_status['cancel'].','.$order_status['success'].','.$order_status['pending'].')','left');
        //$this->db->group_by(array($this->orderLogTable.'.order_status',$this->operatorTable.'.operator_id'));
    /*here group by is off for count_all_results()*/
        //$query = $this->db->get();
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

it returns 1
 and when i use group by it returns 3

but there are 84 rows

how can i solve this problem ?
please i don't want to use num_rows()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051222/how-to-paginate-with-codeigniter-3-0-1

Comment: Did you understand what my problem is?? I am not questioning on how to make pagination.. I am asking how make count for that pagination in this problem.i just want to use count_all_rows()

Comment: Please try to understand my situation,not to check that my question is duplicate or not

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->model('ordermodel');

    //for count all records 
    $count_all = $this->db->count_all('your table');

    $order_status=$this->ordermodel->getOrderStatus();
    $this->db->select($this->operatorTable.'.operator_id,'.$this->orderLogTable.'.order_status');
    $this->db->from($this->operatorTable);
    $this->db->join($this->orderLogTable,$this->orderLogTable.'.operator_id ='.$this->operatorTable.'.operator_id AND '.'date(' . $this->db->dbprefix($this->orderLogTable) . '.order_complete_date) BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromdate)) . '" and"' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todate)) . '" AND '.$this->orderLogTable.'.order_status IN ('.$order_status['cancel'].','.$order_status['success'].','.$order_status['pending'].')','left');
    //$this->db->group_by(array($this->orderLogTable.'.order_status',$this->operatorTable.'.operator_id'));
/*here group by is off for count_all_results()*/
    //$query = $this->db->get();
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

you can use `$this->db->count_all('your table');` for count all records.