# Set pagination with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

I have set the pagination to the page. but it doesn't recognize the variable that represent the pagination link from the controller. How can I solve it?

This is View "member_list.php"

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">

<tr>
    <th class="text-center">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
    <th class="text-center">Number</th>
    <th class="text-center">Type</th>
    <th class="text-center">Unit</th>
    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
</tr>
```

```
<tr>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $member->ID; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->Name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->Letter_Number; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->Letter_Type; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->Unit; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member->Date; ?></td>

<tr>
```

```
<div class="pagination "><?php echo "<li>". $links."</li>";?></div> // it doesn't defined $links variable
```

Here is controller "Main.php"

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {
public function index ()
{       
   redirect('member_list');
}
public function pagination1() {

        $this->load->model('members');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url()."main/pagination1";
        $config["num_links"]= $this->members->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 5;
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->members->record_count(); //method in controller
        $config["use_page_numbers"] = TRUE;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        $data["members"] = $this->members->fetch_data1($config["per_page"],$page);
        $pa_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();  //explode('&nbsp;',$pa_links );
        $data["u_connect"] = $user_connect;
        $this->display('members_list',$data);

}
```

Here is model "members.php"

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Members extends CI_Model {
    public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("in_list");
    }

    public function fetch_data1($limit, $id) {
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get("in_list");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paginate with codeigniter 3.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051222/how-to-paginate-with-codeigniter-3-0-1)

Comment: try like this reference URL https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

I will just post one of mine and you can adapt it

```
public function index()
{
$config['base_url']         = base_url() . '/pages/index/';
$config['total_rows']       = $this->db->count_all_results('posts');
$config['per_page']         = 4;
$config['num_links']        = 4;
$config['uri_segment']      = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['full_tag_open']    = "<div class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close']   = "</div>";
$config['first_link']       = 'First';
$config['last_link']        = 'Last';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$parent = "main";
$this->db->select("title, content, date, last_date, slug")->where('parent', $parent)->where('status', 'publish')->order_by("id", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
if($query->result()){
  $data["mainContent"] = $query->result();
}
$data['title']        = "title";
$data['main_content'] = 'pages/prime';
$this->load->view('pages/includes/template', $data);
```

}
You are using a model, but its little different than mine that doesnt use a model.
In your view, this is all you need AFTER your foreach

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<p><?php echo $links;?></p>
```

insted of this line `<div class="pagination "><?php echo "<li>". $links."</li>";?></div>`

you can also set this configaration in your function

```
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '«';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '»';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```